# backgroundColor comes out as empty string and doesn't change on screen when I set its value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a library called Colorthief that can return the dominant color of an image. I use this function to set the background color of three buttons, like this:

```
var flag = document.getElementById("flag")
var bg_color = colorThief.getColor(flag, 5);  // getColor() function from Colorthief library

var tab_color = [];
for (var i=0; i < bg_color.length; i++) {  // subtracts 20 from each rgb value to get a darker color
    tab_color[i] = bg_color[i] - 20;
}
document.getElementById("tab-button-2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb" + "(" + tab_color + ")";  // applies that color to the non-selected buttons
document.getElementById("tab-button-3").style.backgroundColor = "rgb" + "(" + tab_color + ")";

var selected_tab_color = [];
for (var i=0; i < bg_color.length; i++) {  // subtracts 35 from original color for selected-button
    selected_tab_color[i] = bg_color[i] - 35;
}
document.getElementById("tab-button-1").style.backgroundColor = "rgb" + "(" + selected_tab_color + ")";
```

Later in the code, I use these colors to set the backgroundColor again:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]');
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')

tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget);
        tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
            tabContent.classList.remove('active');
        });
        target.classList.add('active');

        console.log(tab.style.backgroundColor);
        tab.style.backgroundColor = "rgb" + "(" + selected_tab_color + ")"; // applies selected color to the tab that was clicked
        console.log(tab.style.backgroundColor);
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't do anything, and the console.log functions return 1) an empty string (even though I've set the bg color before) 2) the rgb color I want (this doesn't change anything on screen). I can't use CSS classes to change the background color because it's dependent on the variable 'tab_color' or 'selected_tab_color', which are defined earlier in the code. Can anyone point me to the reason why style.backgroundColor has no effect on the buttons on screen?

Here's the html if necessary:

```
<body onload="setBgColors()"> <!-- function that sets certain background colors using Colorthief is called on load -->
    <div id='header'>
        <img src="images/ushankacat.jpg" alt="Flag" id="flag">
        <h1 id="title">Fussajle</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li data-tab-target="#overview">
            <button class="tab-button" id='tab-button-1'>
                Overview
            </button>
        </li>
        <li data-tab-target="#learn">
            <button class="tab-button" id='tab-button-2'>
                Learn
            </button>
        </li>
        <li data-tab-target="#more">
            <button class="tab-button" id='tab-button-3'>
                More
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="overview" data-tab-content class="active"> <!-- Active role sets default tab 'overview' to be shown when page loads. Hidden when other tabs are clicked. -->
        This is a test.
    </div>
    <div id="learn" data-tab-content>
        Learn blah blah blah
    </div>
    <div id="more" data-tab-content>
        Something something something.
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You define tab_color as an array then use it as a string to make the rgb. Also, what happens if the value for R, say, is <20 and you subtract 20 from it? You need to keep the entries to an rgb as <=255. Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might have to do with `selected_tab_color` which you initialized as an **array** and also added some values to it. But later you are accessing it as a **number** I suppose.

Also earlier you set the bg colors for the `button` elements but later inside `forEach`, you are setting those for the `li` elements.